# SIGN_IN_FAILED (12500) on request access to Google Fitness

Tags: android, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

Completely stuck at requesting the access to the FitnessAPI.
There are many workarounds on this but none of them resolve the issue(at least some I could find)

I have obtained OAuth 2.0 credentials at Google Console API (SHA1 and package name are correct and rechecked for dozen times)

Code is simple:

```
GoogleSignIn.requestPermissions(this, AppActivity.FIT_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this), options);
```

The interesting thing (and probably important) is that when I'm running .apk "delivered" to device via my google drive - everything works like a charm, but if I'm running the same release(signed by the same keystore) of the app from Google Play - SIGN_IN_FAILED.

> googleSignInStatus: Status{statusCode=unknown status code: 12500,
>   resolution=null}

What I'm doing wrong?
Any ideas are appreciated.